# Including javax.usb.properties in a Netbeans run

Tags: classpath, netbeans-8, usb4java

I'm trying to run a simple example based on http://usb4java.org/ from a Netbeans 8.1 project Windows 7/64b.
I've created and placed the required javax.usb.properties under the project root directory.
According to the documentation, it must be in the root of the class path.
(cf. http://usb4java.org/quickstart/javax-usb.html)

I made some tries with setting the run configuration by inserting in the VM options (using indifferently -cp or -classpath):
-classpath "." or 
-classpath "D:/WORKSPACES/NETBEANS/USBPrototypeControler".

Unfortunately, no configuration is running as expected. I've got every time the exceptions that says the javax.usb.properties is not found.

How could I do with Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans you need to put the *javax.usb.properties* file to the *src* subfolder in you project directory.